# Set Minimum Disk Space for MSI package

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm creating a Basic MSI package using Install Shield and I want to Set minimum disk space check for the installer and if the requirement doesn't meet it should block the installation.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Installer already supports [File Costing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368593%28VS.85%29.aspx). It also has a [ReserveCost table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371226%28VS.85%29.aspx) that allows you to provide additional weight to component(s).

If you want to ingore all of this and just have some arbitrary high value then you can write a custom action to gather the data needed to enforce your rules and assign a property.  Then you can use that property in a [LaunchCondition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ( InstallShield calls this a Setup Condition ) to block the install.